# How to change the background color of a button in CSS?

Tags: css, wordpress, forms, element, mailchimp

So I'm trying to add some additional CSS on Wordpress and override the color of this form button but nothings happening. Am I entering the right code in here?

[image]

When I inspect the button this comes up...

```html
<form id="mc4wp-form-1" class="mc4wp-form mc4wp-form-1527" method="post" data-id="1527" data-name="Get Started"><div class="mc4wp-form-fields"><div class="input-group">
  <div class="input-icon"><i class="far fa-paper-plane"></i></div>
    <input type="email" placeholder="Your email address" class="form-control" name="email" data-error="e-mail field is required" required="">
  <button type="submit" value="Subscribe" class="item-btn">Subscribe</button>
</div></div><label style="display: none !important;">Leave this field empty if you're human: <input type="text" name="_mc4wp_honeypot" value="" tabindex="-1" autocomplete="off"></label><input type="hidden" name="_mc4wp_timestamp" value="1635448917"><input type="hidden" name="_mc4wp_form_id" value="1527"><input type="hidden" name="_mc4wp_form_element_id" value="mc4wp-form-1"><div class="mc4wp-response"></div></form>
```

The reason why I've tried `button.item-btn::before` is because it shows this in the inspector

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to change the color of the word 'Subscribe' or to change the background color of the button? What does the styling of the ::before and : after show?

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the CSS styling as inline with the button element.

[image]

Inline styling will override the styling from an external css file.

You can also try using the id selector `id=mc4wp-form-1` in your form element to increase the css style specificity to help overwrite the default.

Comment: Can I do this in the additional CSS part of the Wordpress site?

Answer (score 1):

Your selector minus the pseudo-element should do the job.
Maybe there is another background-color definition for buttons in your stylesheets with higher specificity.
You could try raising the specificity of your selector like this:

```
#mc4wp-form-1 button.item-btn {
  background-color: mycolor;
}
```

Comment: This just changes the text to whatever colour is specified :( Not the blue background of the button